# How to make cloud REST API call in Jira atlas connect app

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm new to jira development. 
I created an app in atlas connect cloud app. I want to use REST api calls in this app to access jira core features.

When user installed my app I want to get his projects and other details using rest calls.

How can I authenticate user and use rest api calls.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup of your JIRA instance, you can use the following ways to authenticate users:

- [OAuth](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth/)
- [Basic authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/)
- [Cookie-based authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/cookie-based-authentication/)

For getting a list of projects and other details, you can use [this resource](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.4.1/?_ga=2.239419403.986949531.1568640887-596257740.1548408320) to find out what is possible.

An introduction to the JIRA API can be found [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/).